# How to render Ember component dynamically

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

Rendering a component works well when using `{{component-name}}` in template. I want to render a component from route with dynamic parameters. I've tried this

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  init: function(){
      this.render("components/comp-two", {
        into: "application",
        outlet: "test"
      });

  }
});
```

It successfully renders a template, but component's events(init, didInsertElement) and actions don't work.

How to make events and actions work ?

example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/badaku/1/

Comment: Try with writing this code in renderTemplate method.

Comment: @Vaibhav doesn't seem to work if I replace the  method to renderTemplate. It alerts the temp-one twice, but doesn't render anything. Could you supply an example in jsbin by editing mine ?

Comment: Actually here in route, if you define, then only template gets rendered, it is not considered as a component. You can create a dummy template, inside that you can use your component.

Answer (score 3):

If you give some template name in render method, ember only will render that specific template, it will not be considered as a component.You can create a dummy template, inside that you can use your component.

I have updated your jsBin example
http://jsbin.com/pajirefeta/1/edit

Comment: The thing is I want to pass dynamic parameters like {{comp-print "thisText"}} and `thisText` is downloaded from server and can't be hardcoded in template

Comment: you want to pass some argument to your component?

Comment: Yes. I'm building a modal component which will be rendered into an outlet.

Comment: then you can pass data as {{comp-one compData="thisText"}} and use compData property inside component.

Comment: `thisText` is downloaded from server, and can't be hardcoded in a template :)

Comment: You can have a property for example myProp, which will get the dynamic data(myProp = thisText) and you can assign this to component  {{comp-one compData=myProp}} Here nothing is hard coded, you dynamic property can also be used. Remember, not to put quotes on your property, in that case it will be a  string.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible, but doesn't feel right. Still thanks for solutions ;)

Comment: maybe it doesn't feel right and the Ember Team will add the option to render a component from route, but right now Vaibhav's solution is the right one. Same in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683320/render-view-component-with-parameters-into-named-outlet-ember-js